# Postman- Ariba API ,get only one field from a JSON response object

Tags: sap-ariba

I'm trying to do GET on a SAP Ariba API using Postman tool. I get a response something like below with few fields having a object as type

[image]

Now, 'Project' field has a object with ProjectID and SourceSystem , I want to have my response with only ProjectID . Since the API is from SaaS application I have no hold on the code or API structure.
Can someone please guide me on how can I generate my required response using Postman tool?